# Advanced search interaction with HTML toolbar

Tags: html

I managed to make a youtube search bar using HTML which, when clicked, links user to the youtube page for whatever he typed in the bar.

However, for another part of the assignment, I needed to make a code that does the same thing using only HTML and CSS but the results should be within the year 2010-2019 (custom range). The website in question is https://www.worldscientific.com/search/advanced. I have tried searching for similar cases online but the solutions were either too complicated (involving PHP/bootstrap etc) or had no relevance at all. I have a feeling the solution is very simple but I am just stumped. Please try and explain in simple terms if possible and I have left the snippet of the youtube search bar code for an clearer idea of the level of 'complicatedness'.

```
<form id="vb_yt_search-form" action="http://www.youtube.com/results" method="get" target="_blank">
<input id="vb_yt_search-term" name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" placeholder="search"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not really what you asked, but is doing the job.The code is searching on google rathen than youtube between a custom range 2010-2019. When you press the submit button, the  href will update with text box value. (I know when you will press the submit open it will open an useless tab but I don't bother to fix it, just close and try to press on  text)

```
<a id="test" href="https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2019&ei=5zBDXPf8Dof_swGM4bKADw&q=site%3Ayoutube.com+"> test </a>
<form id="vb_yt_search-form" action="return myFunction()" target="_blank">
<input id="vb_yt_search-term" type="text" maxlength="128"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(){
var value = document.getElementById('vb_yt_search-term').value;
document.getElementById("test").href="https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2010%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2019&ei=5zBDXPf8Dof_swGM4bKADw&q=site%3Ayoutube.com+"+value;
}
</script>
```